# Not able to handle Retrofit Error Response for Post Request in Android

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, httpresponse

I am posting this question after trying everything for 3 days and looking everywhere on google.

I am working on an android project using retrofit and rest API. I am stuck at a place and can't seem to find the solution.

Here is the situation, I am sending a POST request using Retfotit and it either returns 201 for success or 422 for error.

I am able to handle the 201 but when it returns 422 the error comes as JSON like this

```js
{
    "issues": [
        {
            "tag_id": "300000003023",
            "warnings": [],
            "errors": [
                {
                    "error_id": 8,
                    "details": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using postman and HTTP interceptor with retrofit to check the response. I copy and pasted this into the jsonschema2pojo.org website to get POJO model and using the same model to handle the response.body().

```
    getlogres = response.body();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error " +  getlogres.getIssues().get(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But every time there is 422 error I am not able to handle it and get this in Logcat

```
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.beaconblast.btdental.modelsDTS.get.GetPostedLogRes.getIssues()' on a null object reference
```

Please let me know if further information is required and help me out.

The Java POJO model to handle 422

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class GetPostedLogRes {

    @SerializedName("issues")
    @Expose
    private List<Issue> issues = null;

    public List<Issue> getIssues() {
        return issues;
    }

    public void setIssues(List<Issue> issues) {
        this.issues = issues;
    }

}


class Error {

    @SerializedName("error_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer errorId;

    public Integer getErrorId() {
        return errorId;
    }

    public void setErrorId(Integer errorId) {
        this.errorId = errorId;
    }


}




class Issue {

    @SerializedName("tag_id")
    @Expose
    private String tagId;

    @SerializedName("errors")
    @Expose
    private List<Error> errors = null;

    public String getTagId() {
        return tagId;
    }

    public void setTagId(String tagId) {
        this.tagId = tagId;
    }


    public List<Error> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void setErrors(List<Error> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you uploaded you java response classes for both 201 and 422 responses.

Comment: Its not about response code .you have to see null obj and parsing of data . Make sure your error object is not null before using property and for parsing, before using jsonschema2pojo try to wrap response in Object class first and then drill down to response  parsing .

Comment: Hi, @ali73 I have added the response class for 422. There is no class for 201 because I get the result in the header and the body is only an empty array like this  issues: []

Comment: Hi @Godfather, As I am using HTTP interceptor with retrofit I do get a JSON response as mentioned above but it throws an error while handling it.

Comment: Hi @JagtarSingh. I believe your problem is in the way you implement the API. Though we need to see your code, but I think your API should receive an object of a base class which all your responses inherit from. For a certain response your implementation of the API is needed.But you could do what I said and inform us of the result. Good luck :)

Comment: @ali73 The API I am using is developed by another company and I only have the documentation. My only concern is if the HTTP interceptor is showing the response in logcat it means the response is received indeed but I am not able to handle it

Comment: @JagtarSingh I meant the full code of  API in your application. The full code of retrofit